# Combine 3 items to total specific amounts

Tags: linear-algebra, combinations, math-software, ratio

What **Quantities** of **Items $1, 2, 3$** combine to create an **$X, Y, Z$ Target?** Looking for the method.

**$X$ Target: $1000$ | $Y$ Target: $500$ | $Z$ Target: $500$**

**Item $1$ contains:**- $1.8 X | 2.1 Y | 2.0 Z$

**Item $2$ contains:**- $8.8 X | 1.9 Y | 1.7 Z$

**Item $3$ contains:**- $1.7 X | 2.0 Y | 7.4 Z$

Spent $8$ months trying to figure this out; please anyone that can help me. Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like a simple linear system in 3 variables.  Let u,v,w be the quantities of items 1,2,3 respectively.  Then the three equations are: 1.8u+8.8v+1.7w=1000 (X target), 2.1u+1.9v+2.0w=500 (Y target), 2.0u+1.7v+7.4w=500 (Z target).  Hopefully u,v,w will all be non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be $a$ of item $1$, $b$ of item $2$, and $c$ of item $3$.  Then you have three equations, one each for the $X,Y,Z$ targets.  Your equations are $$1.8a+8.8b+1.7c=1000\\2.1a+1.9b+2.0c=500\\1.7a+2.0b+4.7c=500$$
You can rewrite the first as $a=\frac{1000-8.8b-1.7c}{1.8}$ and plug this into the last two, then do the same to eliminate a variable from one, getting a linear equation in the last variable.

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.8a%2B8.8b%2B1.7c%3D1000,2.1a%2B1.9b%2B2.0c%3D500,1.7a%2B2.0b%2B4.7c%3D500) gives a solution $$a\approx 147.911\\ b\approx 79.719\\ c\approx 18.9602$$

Comment: What method can get the value of a, b, c without doing trial and error? Thanks.

Comment: I showed you how to start.  You use each equation in turn to eliminate one variable.  Plug that expression for $a$ into the last two equations and you will be left with two equations in $b,c$.  A similar manipulation on one can get $b=$ some expression in $c$.  Plug that into the last.  You have a system of [linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations)

Comment: Hi. Does this mean that you cannot solve _a_ without working through 2 separate equations for _b_ and _c_? Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.  You need three equations to solve for three unknowns.  If you substitute for $b$ and $c$ first you can get $a$ and quit without learning the values of $b$ and $c$ but you need to use all three equations.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your patience. Are you able to show me how to solve? I'm unsure how to plug the values in.

Comment: You replace $a$ with the expression you found, so the second equation becomes $2.1\frac{1000-8.8b-1.7c}{1.8}+1.9b+2.0c=500$  The $a$ has disappeared.  Do the same in the third and you have two equations in two unknowns.  This is progress.  Now expand the fractions and rearrange one of them to put $b$ on one side by itself the same way and plug into the other.